# Very slow turn-on time BJT (BUV27)

Tags: bjt, frequency, switching

I have been asked to select a replacement BJT for a resonant circuit which uses the now obsolete BUV27.

I have selected some based on V(CE) and hFE but all selected types perform a lot worse (low efficiency, more heat) in the circuit.
The t(on) time of the BUV27 is very high (400-800µs) compared to the storage/turn-off times (0.5µs/0.12 µs). Why is this so?

How would I go about finding a replacement? Most datasheets I have looked at don't even specify the turn-on time and if they do it is a lot faster.

Comment: Since you are trying to find a replacement for an high voltage transistor specifically designed for high speed switching you should have look very carefully at the storage time \$t_s\$: this is the real responsible of the switching performance of the device.

Comment: No standard bipolar transistor needs 800 microseconds to turn-on. What is the datasheet param?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I found the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BUV27-D.PDF) and it does indeed list a turn-on time of 0.4 ms typical, 0.8 ms max.

Answer (score 2):

> The t(on) time of the BUV27 is very high (400-800µs) compared to the
>   storage/turn-off times (0.5µs/0.12 µs). Why is this so?

It's a typo - they meant to say micro seconds as per this data sheet from an alternative supplier: -

[image]

It's always worth digging around to get to the bottm of things if something looks suspicious. I note that both ST and ON semi have made the same error on the data sheets.

> How would I go about finding a replacement?

You start by analysing the circuit and then trying simulations with different transistors - you can't expect to find a replacement by only comparing data sheets.

Comment: Thank you for your input - especially the part on having to understand the circuit. The problem is that data is very limited, it uses a very special transformer that is specially made. But you are right of course. I just would have liked to take a short route.